# How to manage the Error Message Box Size shown when using ErrorFixer methods?

Tags: ewam

[Image with large alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEuL5.png)
I have a situation where the alert box shown on the screen with the message is too large (default size). How to customize the size of the alert box?

Class: aWFErrorFixer
Method: AlertWithErrors

procedure AlertWithErrors(customMessage : CString)
   if customMessage = ''
      self.Message = mlTheFollowingErrorsHaveBeenRaised_
   else
      self.Message = customMessage
   endIf
   if self.Interact(self.Scenario.WFErrorFixerModal, Consultation, True) = rValid
   endIf
endProc

Answer (score 0):

Create a scenario in your aWFErrorFixer called WFErrorFixerMain:

[image]

In the code section of this scenario, the WFErrorFixerMainAgent would be a child of the aUIAgent. The aUIAgent has a method called ChangePos():

```
function InteractWithUser(ExecMode : tExecMode, IsModal : Boolean) return tResult override
   self.ChangePos(4000, 4000, 100, 100)
   return inherited self.InteractWithUser(ExecMode, IsModal)
endFunc
```